# Got error when commit svn files from Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn

I have configure svn with Xcode.

When i try to commit repository files with i got the Error

```
   svn: Commit failed (details follow):
   svn: Error normalizing log message to internal format
   svn: Inconsistent line ending style
```

Anyone have idea, please suggest me. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the message I see that you have `Inconsistent line ending style`. That means that you source files for some reason have mixed EndOfLine styles (e.g. Windows CRLF and *nix CR). You should check through you source files and make sure line endings are uniform and match EndOfLine style your SVN expects.

That kind of thing can happen if you copy/paste code from various sources and/or use different IDEs to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur due to wrong commit message format also. 
like line has enough space to write and you are starting another line with "And", etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error is appear because I have copy and paste commit message from text editor and excel file. I have removed that commit message, and rewrite that commit message again in that section. Do not copy/paste the commit message. This have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem due to mixed end of line style in the SVN commit message.
Most lines were Mac OS X style, but some were copied and had ^M at the end of the line. Removed ^M at the end of a few lines and svn ci -F svn-commit.tmp went through.